# Why am I getting unsupported operand types in this case?

Tags: python, numpy, operands

```
x_list = []
for i in range(N):
  x_list.append(np.random.random)
y_list = []
for i in range(N):
  y_list.append(np.random.random)
c_list = []
for i in range(N):
  xi = x_list[i]
  yi = y_list[i]
  if (pow(xi, 2) + pow(yi, 2) <= 1):
    c_list.append(True)
  else:
    c_list.append(False)
```

In the line with the pow() function, I get an error that says unsupported operand types in the pow() function. It says xi and yi are functions and I can't figure out why; they seem like numbers to me

Comment: Have you tried *looking* at `xi` and `yi`? Try `print(xi)`. You might be surprised what you find.

Comment: You are actually appending the function `numpy.random` to `x_list` and `y_list`. Try using the suitable function by referring the documentation https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending a function `np.random.random` instead of calling the function.  Replace the append lines with

```
x_list.append(np.random.random())
```

and

```
y_list.append(np.random.random())
```

(Note the parentheses)